# InfoPath 2013 Form Library workflow creation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I've created a form in InfoPath 2013 with multiple views.
1st view - Requester (with Submit and Cancel buttons)
2nd view - Action By (with Submit, Approve and Reject buttons)
3rd view - Approved By (with Submit, Approve and Reject buttons)
4th view - Access Denied view

I need to create a workflow using the buttons to submit, approve and reject the form. This form needs to publish in Form Library in SharePoint 2013. 
I saw below [link](https://jamilhaddadin.com/2011/12/03/implementing-workflow-using-infopath-2010-and-sharepoint-designer-2010/) on how to create workflow but it was done in Custom List.

I've added the '`Action`' and '`State`' columns but it does not appear in the InfoPath form to add the functions and rules.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make the first submit option save the form to the form library. Then use SharePoint Designer 2013 to setup a workflow that is set to start when a new item is created.